# Working with Python in Azure Databricks to Write DF to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, scala, dataframe, databricks

We just switched away from Scala and moved over to Python.  I've got a dataframe that I need to push into SQL Server.  I did this multiple times before, using the Scala code below.

```
var bulkCopyMetadata = new BulkCopyMetadata
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(1, "Title", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 128, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(2, "FirstName", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 50, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(3, "LastName", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 50, 0)

val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
  "url"               -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "user"              -> "username",
  "password"          -> "*********",
  "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Clients",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "2500",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
))

df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig, bulkCopyMetadata)
```

That's documented here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector

I'm looking for an equivalent Python script to do the same job.  I searched for the same, but didn't come across anything.  Does someone here have something that would do the job?  Thanks.

Comment: Checkout this article (http://www.nerdsgene.com/Article/BulkCopyToSQLDB#BulkCopy), which describes Bulk copy to SQL server using Spark Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to refer to PySpark offical document [`JDBC To Other Databases`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) to directly write a PySpark dataframe to SQL Server via the jdbc driver of MS SQL Server.

Here is the sample code.

```
spark_jdbcDF.write
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://yourserver.database.windows.net:1433")
    .option("dbtable", "<your table name>")
    .option("user", "username")
    .option("password", "password")
    .save()
```

Or

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}
spark_jdbcDF.write \
    .jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="<your table anem>",
          properties=connectionProperties ).save()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried the same, I am getting, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'` error

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete PySpark code to write a Spark Data Frame to an SQL Server database including where to input database name and schema name:

```
df.write \
.format("jdbc")\
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>:1433;databaseName=<databasename>")\
.option("dbtable", "[<optional_schema_name>].<table_name>")\
.option("user", "<user_name>")\
.option("password", "<password>")\
.save()
```